# Cannot Load Texture in Java (lwjgl)

Tags: java, textures, lwjgl

I have been going about on this for the past 3 hours. 
I'm trying to make a 2D Strategy game in Java using the lwjg libraries, and for starters, I've got stuck at loading a texture for an object (Farmer).
Its giving me this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at _2nd_Branch.Farmer.render(Farmer.java:42)
    at _1st_Branch.CoreGame.render(CoreGame.java:30)
    at _1st_Branch.Game.GameLoop(Game.java:33)
    at _1st_Branch.Game.main(Game.java:13)
```

Here is the code I've been working on (As a way to organize things. Got this from someone on youtube explaining some bits about lwjgl):

Game.java:

```
package _1st_Branch;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;

public class Game {

private static CoreGame coreGame;

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    CD();   
    createGame();
    GameLoop();
    CleanUp();
}

private static void CD()
{
    Window.create(800, 600);
}
private static void createGame()
{
    coreGame = new CoreGame();
}

public static void GameLoop()
{
    while(!Window.isCloseRequested())
    {
        Window.Clear();
        coreGame.input();
        coreGame.logic();
        coreGame.render();
        Display.update();
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE))
        {
            Display.destroy();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
private static void CleanUp()
{
    coreGame.dispose();
    Window.Destroy();
}
}
```

CoreGame.java:

```
package _1st_Branch;
import _2nd_Branch.Farmer;
import _2nd_Branch.Player;
public class CoreGame {

public final static int TILE_SIZE = 64;

private static Player player;   
private static Farmer farmer;   

public CoreGame()
{

    farmer = new Farmer();
}

public void input()
{

}

public void logic()
{

}

public void render()
{

    farmer.render();
}

public void dispose()
{


}

}
```

Window.java:

```
package _1st_Branch;


import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;


import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;


public class Window {

public static void create(int width, int height)
{
    try 
    {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(width, height));
        Display.setTitle("Artyas RTS");
        Display.create();
        initGL();
        initInput();

    } 
    catch (LWJGLException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public static void initGL()
{
    glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, Display.getWidth(), 0, Display.getHeight(), -1, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glLoadIdentity();

}

private static void initInput()
{
    try 
    {
        Keyboard.create();
    } 
    catch (LWJGLException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void Clear()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

public static void Destroy()
{
    Keyboard.destroy();
    Display.destroy();
    System.exit(0);
}

public static void update()
{
    Display.update();
    Display.sync(60);
}

public static boolean isCloseRequested()
{
    return Display.isCloseRequested();
}

}
```

Farmer.java:

```
//CIVILIAN UNIT
package _2nd_Branch;


import java.io.IOException;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.newdawn.slick.Color;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader;
import org.newdawn.slick.util.ResourceLoader;

public class Farmer {


public Farmer() {};
private Texture texture;

public void init() {



    try {

    // load texture from PNG file

    texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG",     ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("Farmer.png"));


    } catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

    }

    }

public void render()
{
    Color.white.bind();

    texture.bind(); 
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);  
    GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); 
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);

    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,0);
    GL11.glVertex2f(400,500);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,0);
    GL11.glVertex2f(450,500);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,1);
    GL11.glVertex2f(450, 550);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,1);
    GL11.glVertex2f(400, 550);

    GL11.glEnd();
}


}
```

I am literally stuck here. If someone could indicate what needs to be done, I will be eternally grateful! I really need to get going on making this project, to learn more about Java.

The texture.bind() function from the Farmer class gives me the error.

Being stuck here, I don't know what it says about me as a programmer.

Comment: Try enabling GL_TEXTURE_2D when you first initialize opengl (before you start all your rendering and updating but after your create your window)

Comment: I've tried in several locations. But I am confused. If you could point at where exactly I must enable. And is it like this:

    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);  ?

Comment: Oh nvm, I see you have it in the correct spot. The issue is that your texture is not being loaded so when you bind it, it tries to bind a null texture. Where exactly within your programs file system is your texture file?

Comment: I've added a res folder inside the project by going to Project Properties -> Libraries -> AddClassFolder.
So I can just add the file name and it goes to get it immediately.

Comment: Then when you load your texture do texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG",     ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("res/Farmer.png"));

Comment: Same error. Tried alot of stuff before. Same error. I must have forgotten something about lwjgl loading textures.

Comment: If possible could your print screen and share your file structure, that is most likely the issue.

Comment: Here is Farmer Part 1:http://i.imgur.com/vefDjQ1.png

Farmer Part 2: http://i.imgur.com/ViuXZMr.png

Do you require the other classes as well? Just say.

Comment: File structure, not the actual code. The project explorer bar with all the folders. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: This: http://i.imgur.com/Un8xk3X.png ?

Comment: Yep, now where is your image inside of that?

Comment: There: http://i.imgur.com/jxSXuMq.png

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure why it isn't working. Try building it into a jar file and run that, if it doesn't work then open up the jar and see if the texture is inside the jar.

Comment: Hehe...How do I do that?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDsGTiACqnw&list=SP210C2267A8922854&index=9 watch this, also you may need to redo your res folder since you have it as a source folder.

Comment: I did it. Deleted the folder, recreated it. Dragged the image into it. Copied it. And still it does the same thing. I am either really confused and/or retarded. Do you want the Project? To see for yourself?

Comment: You know what, if I can't fix this by today. I will start tommorow to follow Bucky's tutorials. He's awesome. Din't even know he had java tutorials. (Used his videos to learn about C++) Thanks man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never call Farmer.init() which loads the texture. You only call the constructor in CoreGame. Either you should call init() from inside the Farmer constructor or call init after calling the constructor in CoreGame. I recommend calling init() from CoreGame, and continue to keep texture loading away from the constructor simply because if you initialize and have to call the constructor to Farmer before you have created your display and initialized OpenGL (Window.initGL()) you don't want to load the texture. Loading a texture with slick before the display is created and opengl is initialized can cause a NullpointerException in TextureLoader.

Comment: Yep. It loaded it fine. Thanks alot!